# Create a matrix of words occurring in a Pandas data frame with text strings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas data frame with a column of text data. I want to compare each row of this text data with a list of words that I'm interested in. The comparison should result in a matrix that shows the occurrence of the word (0 or 1) in the text of that row of data.

Input data frame:

```
text
That bear talks
The stone rocks
Tea is boiling
The bear drinks tea
```

Input list of words:

```
[bear, talks, tea]
```

Result:

```
text                 bear  talks  tea
That bear talks      1     1      0
The stone rocks      0     0      0
Tea is boiling       0     0      1
The bear drinks tea  1     0      1
```

I found some information on sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer but from what I understand it just takes the whole data frame and breaks it down in component words and counts those. What I want to do is do it on a very limited list.

With sklearn I did the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer

countvec = HashingVectorizer()

countvec.fit_transform(resultNLdf2.text)
```

But that gives me the following:

```
<73319x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1105683 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Which seems a bit big to work with unless I could select on the words I want from this sparse matrix but I don't know how to work with it.

I'm sorry if I used the wrong words to explain this problem, not sure if you would call this a matrix for example.

**edit**

The true data i'm working on is rather large, 1264555 rows with strings of tweets. At least i've learned not to over simplify a problem :-p. This makes some of the given solutions (Thanks for trying to help!!) not work because of memory issues or just being extremely slow. This was also a reason I was looking at sklearn.

with:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

words = ['bear', 'talks', 'tea']

countvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=words)

countvec.fit_transform(resultNLdf2.text)
```

you can actually limit the words you want to look at by giving a simple list. But this leaves me with the problem that it is in a format I'm not sure what to do with as described above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use use [Series.str.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)

```
>>> print df.join(df.text.str.get_dummies(' ').loc[:, ['bear', 'talks', 'tea']])
                 text  bear  talks  tea
0      That bear talks     1      1    0
1      The stone rocks     0      0    0
2       Tea is boiling     0      0    0
3  The bear drinks tea     1      0    1
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work on my complete set of data because I get a memory error. To give an idea of the true data: 1264555 rows with strings of twitter text. With just a small subset it does seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

After testing with the solutions given to my initial question, I wanted to stick with sklearn because it seems extremely fast and seems to have no problems with the considerable amount of data I'm working with. To stick with the *'bear, talks, tea'* example here is the solution I'm working with now:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame(["That bear talks", "The stone rocks", "Tea is boiling", "The bear drinks tea"], columns=['text'])

words = ['bear', 'talks', 'tea']

countvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=words)

dfFinal = pd.DataFrame(countvec.fit_transform(df.text).toarray(), index=df.text, columns=countvec.get_feature_names())
```

Of course I'm still interested to hear why this or other solutions are good or about things I should take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a limited list, you could loop over the words in the list and execute this for each word:

```
df['bear'] = df['text'].str.contains('bear')
```

Comment: This gives me the following warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.  It does work however, I might use it

Comment: Weird, I don't get any warning on this dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame(["That bear talks", "The stone rocks", "Tea is boiling", "The bear drinks tea"], columns=['text'])`.

Comment: You are right, with the example I don't get an error either. I was testing on my actual data :)

Comment: In general, using `df.loc[:, 'bear']` instead of `df['bear']` could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python string count](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) for this.

```
import pandas as pd

x= ["That bear talks","The stone rocks","Tea is boiling","The bear drinks tea"]
words = ['bear', 'talks', 'tea']

out=pd.DataFrame(index=x,columns=words)

for i in range(0,out.shape[0]):
    for word in words:
        out.ix[i,str(word)]= out.index[i].count(str(word))

print(out)

                    bear talks tea
That bear talks        1     1   0
The stone rocks        0     0   0
Tea is boiling         0     0   0
The bear drinks tea    1     0   1
```