# Run-time crashes when using CountVectorizer to create a term frequency dataframe from a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I am new to python and doing a data analysis project and would request some help.
I have a dataframe of 400,000 rows and it has columns: ID, Type 1 Categories, Type 2 Categories, Type 3 Categories, Amount, Age, Fraud.

The Category columns are column of lists. This list contains different terms which I want to take and create a matrix that counts and shows how many times a particular terms occurs in that row (with a column per term and frequency).

So the goal is to create a dataframe of sparse matrix, with each of those unique categories becoming a column - my dataset has over 2000 different categories - maybe thats why the count vectorizer is not good for this?

I tried two methods one using a [count vectorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33372142) and another using [for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33367896)

but Count Vectorizer crashes everytime it runs.
The second method is far too slow. Therefore, I was wondering if there anyway to improve these solutions.

I also split the dataframe into multiple chunks and it still causing problems

```py
Example:
+------+--------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
|  ID  |             Type 1 Category                | Amount  | Fraud   |
+------+--------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| ID1  | [Lex1, Lex2, Lex1, Lex4, Lex2, Lex1]       |  110.0  |    0    |
| ID2  | [Lex3, Lex6, Lex3, Lex6, Lex3, Lex1, Lex2] |  12.5   |    1    |
| ID3  | [Lex7, Lex3, Lex2, Lex3, Lex3]             |  99.1   |    0    |
+------+--------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
col = 'Type 1 Category'

# prior to this, I combined the entire dataframe based on ID
# this was from old dataframe where each row had different occurrence of id
# and only one category per row 
terms =  df_old[col].unique() 


countvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=terms)

# create bag of words

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(countvec.fit_transform(df[col]).toarray(),
                              columns=countvec.get_feature_names(),
                              index=df.index))

# drop original column of lists
df = df.drop(col, axis = 1)


##### second split dataframe to chunks using np.split

df_l3 = df_split[3]

output.index = df_l3.index
# Assign the columns.
output[['ID', '[col]']] = df_l3[['ID', '[col]']]

# split dataframe into chunks and 114305 is where the index starts
last = 114305+int(df_l3.shape[0])

for i in range(114305,last):
  print(i)
  for word in words:
      output.ix[i,str(word)] = output[col][i].count(str(word))
```

Runs of memory for count vectorizer, second one does not count frequencies anymore. Worked for chunk 1 where index starts from zero but does not for the others.